# Value help dialog does not work on small screen size

Tags: sapui5

I'm facing a weird issue regarding UI5's value help request. It works fine on a big monitor but it doesn't display on a smaller screen (phone and even when I try phone screen in Chrome Developer Tools).

I know that UI5 handles different screen sizes in different ways but I haven't had enough knowledge to figure out why/where is the problem?
Did anyone face the issue before? Any help would be appreciated, thank you all.

This is Controller

```
onValueHelpForSite : function(oEvent) {

        var oValueHelpDialog = this.getFragmentForValueHelp();
        oValueHelpDialog.open();

        ...

        oValueHelpDialog.getTable().bindRows(
            this.getEntitySet(
                "ODATA_01_DEFAULT_SITE_SET",
                "ODATA_01"
            )
        );
    }
```

This is View fragment

```
createContent: function(oController) {

    var oValueHelpDialog = new sap.ui.comp.valuehelpdialog.ValueHelpDialog({
        title : oController.getStrTextSite(),
        supportMultiselect : false,
        supportRanges : false,
        supportRangesOnly : false,
        ...
        ok: function(oControlEvent) {
            oController.setDefaultSiteFromHelp(oControlEvent);
            oValueHelpDialog.close();
        },
        cancel: function(oControlEvent) {
            oValueHelpDialog.close();
        },
        afterClose: function() {
            oValueHelpDialog.destroy();
        }
    });

    ...     

    return oValueHelpDialog;
}
```

Comment: Share the code which is relevant

Comment: Hi, I added code. Hope it can help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using a little bit outdate version of UI5, 1.30.

If I develop a new program using version 1.8, the problem is solved.

I am not sure if it is the cause but I hope it help.